# 3d graphics/diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, 3d

Is there a convenient way to create a 3d graphic/diagram like the following in LaTeX (e.g. with tikz)? I'm aware that convenience is a point of view, however I would describe myself as a newbie to tikz.

[image: flow of energy]

Comment: Yes, you can make 3d diagrams with tikz. Just give it 3d coordinates like (0,0,0). See tikz manual page 572.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Usually on this site question should include your first attempt at writing appropriate code.

Comment: The most "convenient" way to include charmingly hand-drawn sketches like this one is just to use `includegraphics` instead of trying to re-create it in Tikz or Asymptote or Metapost.